# Writing a .txt file from SQL row's data

Tags: mysql, sql, django, express

I am setting up a application with Django/ExpressJS(prototyping) and vueJS and MYSQL.
One goal is generate .txt file from data store in row. Each row will have one .txt file and user can download them via button click.
Quit not sure how to do that, Can use SQL query but hope there is some way via Django. 
I am new with Django, experience in ExpressJS.

Comment: Writting a MySQL query like `SELECT * FROM ... INTO OUTFILE...` or `SELECT * FROM ... DUMPFILE...` is alot less work that writting (OOP) code to do the same.. But one problem you might need to escape some [Special Character Escape Sequences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) manually with nested `REPLACE()` functions.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for suggestion. Yes using SQL query is fairly easy, but the text format of that file should be maintain some strict rules. This formatting I guess is not possible via sql.